# Como obter o id do onclick que foi executado

Tags: javascript

Bom é o seguinte, eu tenho um button que tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
<button id="goncalo" onclick="ativafuncao()">Goncalo</button>
```

Como faço para a função ativafuncao(), saber que foi o id "goncalo" que chamou ela?

Espero que tenha me feito entender.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível passar `this` na chamada de função e capturar o id do elemento na função.

```js
function ativafuncao(obj){
  console.log(obj.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="teste" onclick="ativafuncao(this)">Clicar</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar this.id como parâmetro da função ativafuncao() desse modo:

```
<button id="goncalo" onclick="ativafuncao(this.id)">Goncalo</button>
```

Veja o código funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/1t4w1z0b/1/)

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode usar a variável de evento desta maneira:

**HTML**

```
<button id="meu-botao">Clica</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var meuBotao = document.getElementById('meu-botao');
meuBotao.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Target se refere ao botão que foi clicado.